# Is there a way to dynamically modify an Origen Parameters set?

Tags: origen-sdk

Is there a way to dynamically modify an [Origen parameters set](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/parameters/)?  Specifically:

1. Delete a parameter set
2. Add in new keys to the parameter set

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, after completion of a `define_params` block the parameter set is frozen and actively blocked from changes:

https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/blob/master/lib/origen/parameters.rb#L29

I would support the addition of an `update_params` method which would copy the contents of the existing parameter set into a new (unfrozen) one, then take updates, then freeze it.

Comment: Are there any existing methods (pub or private) that would serve to merge parameter sets?  Or would this require exporting to Hash and handling the update there and then recreating a new parameter set?

Comment: I haven't looked under the hood here for a long time, so you'll need to dig around, but on the face of it, this looks like it should be useful - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/blob/master/lib/origen/parameters.rb#L36